# Phantom and Align Environment

Tags: align

Is there any way to 'phantom' text within the align environment?

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\phantom
{
a & = b \\
& = c
}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Apparently, if there a tab alignment character in the argument of the phantom command, compilation will stop. I was trying to make the text within the align environment appear as blank text. Curiously, if I have a cases environment with the tab alignment character inside it, phantom will work when it surrounds the cases environment.

Thanks.

Comment: you could `\phantom` each individual 'cell'

Comment: you could pack the alignment in a `minipage` with the `\phantom` wrapped around that, but unfortunately it would foul up the vertical spacing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you "hide" the tab alignment `&` from `align`, it will fail to work as expected. This is only because `&` is read as part of the argument to `\phantom`, which knowns nothing about `&` and its use. As such, you either have to spread the `\phantom` across the aligned components, or use an altogether different approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a & = b + c \\
  \phantom{a} & \phantom{{} = b} + c \\ % Hides some components of above line
   & = d + e \\
   & \phantom{{}= d} + e % Hides some components of above line
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, some components were left untouched to indicate how some spacing correction is sometimes required when using `\phantom` (for example, when hiding the relation `=`).

The reason why `\phantom` around an *entire* `cases` structure works is because the tab alignment character is buried within the environment where it makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I thought that future searchers might appreciate this alternative, which in complex situation is much easier than splitting out the phantoms over the tab stops. It uses `pgf`, which has `\pgfsys@begininvisible` and `\pgfsys@endinvisible` for this purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\pgfinvisible{\pgfsys@begininvisible}
\newcommand\pgfshown{\pgfsys@endinvisible}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a & = b + c \\
  \pgfinvisible a & = b\pgfshown + c \\ % Hides some components of above line
   & = d + e \\
  \pgfinvisible  & = d\pgfshown + e % Hides some components of above line
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The output:
[image: align with phantoms crossing tab boundaries]

This is the mechanism that [beamer's overlay system](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/base/beamerbaseoverlay.sty) uses.

In fact, you can put this around the entire `align*` environment, which doesn't work with `\phantom` and is what the question asker originally wanted. Then one must be careful about introducing extra vertical space.

I should add here that, apparently, this does not remove the text from the PDF (it gets offset somewhere where it won't appear on the page, as far as I understand) so this is not a suitable approach for redaction.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easier to use `textcolor` with white:

```
\textcolor{white}{sometext}
```

You need the `color` package.

Comment: Unusual approach, however I don't consider it good in this case. There are two reasons: (1) unnecessary usage of colours, (2) the hidden text is still copy-pastable, which might be an issue, especially if it's hidden to achieve correct spacing, because then the text _does not_ belong to the output but still would get copied.

Comment: Also, this text is still read by automated resume reading programs, **careful what you write!**